# Jboss developer studio not able fetch/push with GIT

Tags: eclipse, git, jboss-developer-studio

In my project i use Git verisoning. I use Jboss developer studio.
When i try to make the team->syncronize workspace , i get this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHysv.png)

this is my configuration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHyuS.png)

If a can do fetch with cmd git, it works.

Comment: could you, please, show what you have in the Error log view? Also, please, edit your question and add how exactly you do fetch from cmd

Answer (score 0):

Why is your remote url only https:// ? That's not a valid repo

Comment: the repo is correct , i hide it. but it's ok, maybe something with certification.

Comment: Can you provide console log info as @bdshadow asked? Hard to debug without info.